# Nested if else in Crystal Reports

Tags: syntax, if-statement, crystal-reports

I want to nest if-else statements in Crystal Reports, but I don't know the necessary syntax. How can I arrange something like this:

```
if table1.id <> "1" then
   if table1.name <> "a" then
      var1 := "Hello"
   else
      var1 := "Hi"
else
   var1 := "Bye"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use parenthesises to avoid ambiguity within nested `if..else` structures:

```
if {table1.id} <> 1 then
   (if {table1.name} <> "a" then
      var1 := "Hello"
   else
      var1 := "Hi";)
else
   var1 := "Bye";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also nest your nested if statements and end with a semicolon on the last condition.

```
Stringvar variable

if {@cond}=1 then
  variable:="cond1"
else
  if {@cond}=2 then
    variable:="cond2"
else
   variable:="otherwise";

variable
```