# crystal if on multiple fields

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports, formula, crystal-reports-2011

I am creating a group value in Crystal my formula is

```
if table1.field1 = "R" then "Return"
else
    if table2.field1 = "D" then "DRY"
else 
    if table2.field1 = "F" then 3rd "FREEZE
else "ERROR"
```

When I run the report with the first test, some records group correctly and others seem to be completely excluded from the formula because the report shows them in a group where the group name is blank. Others are included in the correct group based on the formula.

Comment: I couldn't understand your issue but your code has errors... are you sure this is code is working? error in this part.... `if table2.field1 = "F" then 3rd "FREEZE`

Comment: Personally, I use nested case structure instead. `Select {table1.field1} Case "R" : "Return" Default : Select {table2.field1} Case "D" : "DRY" Case "F" : "Freeze" Default : "ERROR"` For more on nested If Then Else Thens though see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184169/nested-if-else-in-crystal-reports)

Comment: @Siva Sorry for the typo.  I have found the problem.  table1.field1 contains null values, so I added a test (not isnull(table1.field1) and the formula works as intended.  Thanks all for your help.