# Can we set barcode size conditionally in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports with visual studio to generate a barcode report using the following formula

```
if Length({table.column1})>0 then
'*' + {table.column1} + '*'
Else
""
```

It is working fine but I want to conditionally set the barcode size.

From here i got to know how to execute nested if else in Crystal reports -

[Nested if else in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184169/nested-if-else-in-crystal-reports)

But when i try to implement the same in the above formula it gives me error.

I want :

```
If column1 is less than 10 
Then 
Font be 20 
Else
Font be 18
```

What I tried:

```
if Length({table.column1})>0 
then
(
'*' + {table.column1} + '*';
If Length({table.column1})<10
Then
20
Else
18
)
Else
""
```

I get error that A number is required here in `else ""`

Comment: The empty double quotes implies the outer ELSE statement should return a String datatype when the formula field is expecting a Numeric datatype.  Replace the empty double quotes with a number to clear the error about a number being required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression for the font size needs to be provided in a completely different location:

Right-click the formula field on the report layout. ***Select Format
Field...***
Select the ***Font*** tab. Enter the formula using the button for the font size expression:
[image]